# i want to convert an .ui file to .py file but it caught an ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8

here is the error:

```
D:\Jarvis Project>pyuic5 -x jarvisUI.ui -o JarvisUI.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python\Scripts\pyuic5.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems like you have different locations of python paths. Where did you install it? How did you install PyQt?

Comment: i install it on my D drive, i install pyqt by pip install pyqt5